# Как может пользователь или ОС Android убить Services?

Tags: android, service

Всем привет! Собственно, вопрос краток: слышал, что система может убить Service при нехватки памяти. Есть ли другие способы и/или ситуации, при которых система также убьет Service?
И есть-ли какие-нибудь способы, чтобы пользователь убил Service? (кроме удаления приложения)
Например, умрёт ли Service, если пользователь очистит Storage и кэш приложения?